# ImportError: cannot import name 'SAVE_STATE_WARNING' from 'torch.optim.lr_scheduler'

Tags: import, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering

I am attempting to issue this statement in a jupyter Notebook.

```
from transformers import BertForQuestionAnswering
```

I get the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'SAVE_STATE_WARNING' from 'torch.optim.lr_scheduler' (C:\Users\sbing.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\lr_scheduler.py)

Here is the complete stack:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 from transformers import BertForQuestionAnswering
>
> ~.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\transformers_*init*_.py in 
> 624
> 625     # Trainer
> --> 626     from .trainer import Trainer
> 627     from .trainer_pt_utils import torch_distributed_zero_first
> 628 else:
>
> ~.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py in 
> 67     TrainerState,
> 68 )
> ---> 69 from .trainer_pt_utils import (
> 70     DistributedTensorGatherer,
> 71     SequentialDistributedSampler,
>
> ~.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer_pt_utils.py in 
> 38     SAVE_STATE_WARNING = ""
> 39 else:
> ---> 40     from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import SAVE_STATE_WARNING
> 41
> 42 logger = logging.get_logger(**name**)
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'SAVE_STATE_WARNING' from 'torch.optim.lr_scheduler' (C:\Users\sbing.conda\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\lr_scheduler.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the transformer package to the latest version. You can achieve it by running this code:

```
!pip install transformers==4.11.3.
```

For me, there is no error after updating. Refer to these links [official resource](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/8979) and [this](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/9060)

Comment: remove dot after the command